# How can I combine the date into a dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm having trouble with Dictionary.

For example,

My current data

```
["date": "2018-01-01", "name": "New Year"], ["date": "2018-01-31", "name": "Public holiday"],["date": "2018-02-14", "name": "Valentine's Day"], ["date": "2018-02-28", "name": "Public Holiday"]
```

How can I transform to

```
["month": ["January": ["date": "2018-01-01", "name": "New Year"], ["date": "2018-01-31", "name": "Public holiday"]],["February": ["date": "2018-02-14", "name": "Valentine's Day"], ["date": "2018-02-28", "name": "Public Holiday"]]]
```

Comment: First question: Did you try anything? Second question: Are you able to find the month at least?

Comment: As @Larme said. Did you try anything to share? It does not look like a simple transform. You should try first to reach some point.

Comment: @Kamran I managed to do ["month": ["January": ["2018-01-01", "2018-01-31"]]] but its not what I want. I hardcoded the "January" and "month" but the date I append into 12 different array and check if there is "01", "02" and so on and append into the dictionary. The problem is I have 3 different data need to be transformed. They all have different dates

Comment: Read the documentation for `DateFormatter`

Comment: can you add some codes, which you had tried

Comment: Data in question does not look properly structured. I think you are missing [ ] for outer arrays. For key "January", value should also be an array. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary` has a method [`init(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init) which can do that in a pretty smart way.

Then `date` parameter is converted to `Date` and then to the month name with a `DateFormatter`

```
let array = [["date": "2018-01-01", "name": "New Year"],
             ["date": "2018-01-31", "name": "Public holiday"],
             ["date": "2018-02-14", "name": "Valentine's Day"],
             ["date": "2018-02-28", "name": "Public Holiday"]]

let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: array) { (item) -> String in
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    guard let dateString = item["date"],
        let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) else  { return "Unknown" }
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}

print(["months" : dictionary])
```

Comment: I have one question how do I get "January" for my label. Let's say let data = data[indexPath.row] cell.lbl.text = "(data["month"])" instead of giving me all the value I just want "January"

Comment: In this case I'd group the dictionary by month **numbers** (which can be sorted), then get the `keys` of the dictionary, sort them and  use a lookup table to get the month name for the number.

Comment: Can you explain more or give some examples?? I'm very new to programming.

Comment: My code groups by month **name**. If you replace `(item) -> String` with `(item) -> Int` and `formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"; return formatter.string(from: date)` with `return Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)` the code groups by **number** (1-12). `dictionary.keys.sorted()` returns a sorted list. The you can use a list  `let monthNames = ["January", "February", ... "December"]` and get the name with `monthNames[monthNumber - 1]`. `monthNumber` is one of the sorted keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) to read the `String` format dates (`yyyy-MM-dd`) into [`Date`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) instances, and subsequently re-use the formatter to extract the full month names (`MMMM`) from the dates as your `String` key.

Combine this with `reduce(into:)` to process the `data` array:

```
let data = [
    ["date": "2018-01-01", "name": "New Year"],
    ["date": "2018-01-31", "name": "Public holiday"],
    ["date": "2018-02-14", "name": "Valentine's Day"],
    ["date": "2018-02-28", "name": "Public Holiday"]
]

let monthCategorizedData = data
    .reduce(into: (result: [String: [[String: String]]](),
                   formatter: DateFormatter(),
                   calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian))) {(args, data) in
    var month = "Unknown"
    args.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" // format: read date from string
    if let date = data["date"].flatMap({ args.formatter.date(from: $0)}) {
        args.formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"   // format: read month (as string) from date
        month = args.formatter.string(from: date)
    }
    args.result[month] = args.result[month, default: []] + [data]
}.result

print(monthCategorizedData)
/* ["January":  [["date": "2018-01-01", "name": "New Year"],
                 ["date": "2018-01-31", "name": "Public holiday"]],
    "February": [["date": "2018-02-14", "name": "Valentine\'s Day"],
                 ["date": "2018-02-28", "name": "Public Holiday"]]] */
```

In case of data with invalid dates (`String` form to `Date` fails, or `"date"` key does not exist in the `data`), the above will categorize them into the key `Unknown`. If you'd rather just discard such data (as such a failure should be unexpected), you can modify the above to:

```
let monthCategorizedData = data
    .reduce(into: (result: [String: [[String: String]]](),
                   formatter: DateFormatter(),
                   calendar: Calendar(identifier: .gregorian))) {(args, data) in
    args.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" // format: read date from string
    if let date = data["date"].flatMap({ args.formatter.date(from: $0)}) {
        args.formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"   // format: read month (as string) from date
        let month = args.formatter.string(from: date)
        args.result[month] = args.result[month, default: []] + [data]
    }
}.result
```

---

Further nesting the result one more level into the value for a `"month"` key in  a `[String: [String : [[String : String]]]]` is straight-forward:

```
let categorizedData = ["month": monthCategorizedData]

print(categorizedData)
/* ["month": ["January":  [["date": "2018-01-01", "name": "New Year"],
                           ["date": "2018-01-31", "name": "Public holiday"]],
              "February": [["date": "2018-02-14", "name": "Valentine\'s Day"],
                           ["date": "2018-02-28", "name": "Public Holiday"]]]] */
```

Comment: I have one question how do I get "January" for my label.
Let's say let data = data[indexPath.row]
cell.lbl.text = "\(data["month"])" 
instead of giving me all the value I just want "January"

Answer (score 1):

while im not expert but problem for me seem to be just how u get from 
"date" = "year-month-day" the value of month
if u could be able to some how cut? or get just 5th and 6th character it will become a number of month u need 
based on that u could use if or switch and make an array of dictionaries
or even just dictionaries which u would then add into array as u wish.

so after getting this month number it would be like this :

var dict: [String: [[String:String]]] = [:]

dict["janury"] = [["2012-01-12":"Event"],["2012-01-13":"event2"]]

if monthNumber == 1 {

```
dict["janury"]?.append(["2012-01-14":"event3"])
```

}

and then for each month u would need new if total of 12 eventually switch with 12 statements

as for how to get this value of string i don't know yet, but i'm almost sure google could help it or someone with better experience than my